# how to return full object with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the full document (even with the undefined and empty keys ) .

here is my schema :

```
var userSchema =  new Schema({
  username      : {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}} ,
  password      : String ,
  email         : {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}} ,
  gender        : String 
})
```

lets say the for some user the gender isnt defined  , when i query i only get  the username, password and email .. how can i get the gender as well ?!

sorry if there is any wrong technical terms .

Comment: If there's no gender, why would gender be present?

Comment: i want to retrieve the whole document so i can send it as json to my template .. if the gender is not present that will cause an error .. and i don't want to deal with that on the front end . i know that this is not the way that mongodb works. but this is where im at !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use the `default` attribute in a type definition to provide a default value.

```
var userSchema =  new Schema({
  username      : {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}} ,
  password      : String ,
  email         : {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}} ,
  gender        : {type: String, default: "Unknown" } 
})
```

For more information, the documentation is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default).